# HTML5 game not working - phaser.js

Tags: javascript, html, ios, debugging

## Basic rundown:

I am developing the game via JS with the aid of [howlerjs.com] for audio and [phaser.io] for the graphics and physics. The game is hosted at [ygdqe.co.nf]. The code I currently have is [main.js], [index.html], [phaser.js] and [howler.js] and they can all be found in the root of the domain. My main problem is when loading the [index.html] - which has links to all the mentioned js - it just shows a blank page.

Just to mention, I currently do not have a laptop so I have loaded all the code in chrome on IOS.

### Links:

[phaser.js]:http://ygdqe.co.nf/phaser.js

[main.js]:http://ygdqe.co.nf/main.js

[howlerjs.com]:https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js

[phaser.io]:https://phaser.io

[ygdqe.co.nf]:http://ygdqe.co.nf

[howler.js]:http://ygdqe.co.nf/howler.js

[index.html]:http://ygdqe.co.nf/index.html

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'KABOOMSSS', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
function preload() {
game.stage.backgroundColor = '#85b5e1';
game.load.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

game.load.image('player', 'phaser-dude.png');
game.load.image('platform', 'platform.png');

}
var player;
var platforms;
var cursors;
var jumpButton;
var xtime;

function create() {
var xtime = 0;

player = game.add.sprite(100, 200, 'player');

game.physics.arcade.enable(player);

player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
player.body.gravity.y = 500;

platforms = game.add.physicsGroup();

platforms.create(500, 150, 'platform');
platforms.create(-200, 300, 'platform');
platforms.create(400, 450, 'platform');

platforms.setAll('body.immovable', true);

cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
jumpButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
game.input.onTap.add(onTap, this);
var sound = new Howl({
src: ['http://soundimage.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Automation.mp3']
});
function onTap () {

if (xtime == 0) {
} else if (xtime != 0) {
sound.play;
}
var xtime = (xtime + 1);
}

function update () {

game.physics.arcade.collide(player, platforms);

player.body.velocity.x = 0;

if (cursors.left.isDown)
{
    player.body.velocity.x = -250;
}
else if (cursors.right.isDown)
{
    player.body.velocity.x = 250;
}

if (jumpButton.isDown)
{
   player.body.velocity.y = -400;
}
}
function render () {

}
```

Comment: you have a typo error (check your console: " missing } after function body")" `function create(){...`

Comment: Thanks! Spent hours looking through code, probably gone past that error 100s of times.

Comment: Another question, can anyone get any sound working? It could just be my iPad. — to get sound working U should be able to tap twice.